# Spring boot - all files from resource has equals lastModified()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I fetch list of files in my src/main/resources/db from my junit test

```
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
Resource [] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:db/*")
```

It is work fine. I can create loop and for each resource get file name: `resource.getFileName()`

I need to know which file is latest. Unfortunately method: `lastModified()` return the same long for each resource file.
Do you know how to get the newest file?

Comment: How are you running the project? Are you performing a clean before you run? Your resources get picked from the target directory at runtime, so each time you clean and run,  you will be deleting and creating a copy of the resource file from your src/main/resources into your target directory.

Comment: Yes, you have right. Thanks. After each clean in my maven project - the lastModified() long is new for all files. So, is there any solution to get newest file from the resource path ?

Comment: My 2 cents: you should never rely on last modification date. As you noticed, it is updated whenever you build your application. Have another logic (maybe append the writing timestamp to each file name, or store each in a directory whose name is the last writing timestamp, etc.).